# Can I use python with giraph?

Tags: python, graph, hadoop, graph-theory

Is python supported on Giraph and if it is, is it as well-supported as python is on Hadoop or well it lead to considerably worse performance than using raw Java?

Comment: Interesting question, more specifically, does Hadoop Streaming (http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.2/streaming.html) works with something like Apache Giraph (i.e. a map only job)?

Comment: Two years later and I'd like to know whether a C-Python binding is available. Is this on the radar, or is Jython the only choice? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Giraph does now support python scripting through jython, in the trunk version.

This is the related issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GIRAPH-683

Comment: Are there any tutorials / examples in Python that show how to begin?  I can find plenty of Java examples for Giraph, but I don't know how to translate them into Python, or more importantly, how to load the modules to begin.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming out to a scripting language is not yet supported but certainly would be a good addition.  Patches welcome.